# jOOQ - difference between fetchAny and fetchOne

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is there a (real) difference between `fetchAny()` and `fetchOne()`?  Both return exact one record. The API documentation is the same, but the implementation (on github) is different.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The intent of the two methods is different:

- [`ResultQuery.fetchOne()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne--)

  > **Returns:**
  >
  > The resulting record or null if the query returns no records.
  >
  > **Throws:**
  >
  > [`TooManyRowsException`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/TooManyRowsException.html) - if the query returned more than one record
- [`ResultQuery.fetchAny()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchAny--)

  > **Returns:**
  >
  > The first resulting record or null if the query returns no records.

In essence, when you use `fetchOne()` the query must return 0 or 1 record. When you use `fetchAny()` the query may return any number of records, and if any record is returned by the database, the first one fetched from the JDBC result set will be returned.

Notice that `fetchOne()` will thus try to fetch 2 records from the JDBC driver (to decide whether `TooManyRowsException` needs to be thrown), while `fetchAny()` only fetches at most 1 record.

Comment: Any performance benefits by using fetchOne() ?Can i assume that it stops finding the record throughout the table if it has found already ?

Comment: @vinaypatlolla: jOOQ will fetch at most two records from the JDBC `ResultSet` (The first one is returned, and the second one is needed to check if `fetchOne()` needs to throw `TooManyRowsException`). You should, however, still ensure that both 1) your JDBC driver doesn't cache too many rows, 2) your database doesn't actually load all rows in the cursor. Ideally, you'll use jOOQ's `limit(1)` clause, too.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder .And by the way JOOQ is awsome :)I 've been using it since 2 months and helping us a lot .

Comment: I have a question @Lukas Eder .The jooq generated classes were all synch with the database name and now i want to go with a new schema with same tables ie i will be working on new tables only in this schema  ,when i generate classes now i see all of my classes with new schema_name .So how can i work with multiple schemas without many changes in my classes ?

Comment: @vinaypatlolla maybe this helps: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping/

Comment: Oh yes ! This is what exactly we are looking for .Thanks Lukas

Comment: i give an extra point if you mention `fetchSingle` ;)

Comment: @DanielAlder: The question was about `fetchAny()` and `fetchOne()`. THough if you provide a `fetchSingle()` based answer, then I'll definitely upvote it!

Answer (score 5):

[The javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.6.x/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html) explains the difference. `fetchAny()` returns the first record, whereas `fetchOne()` expects the query to return zero or one record, and throws an exception if the query returned more than one record.